# How to programmatically scrape Fan Box Iframe using C# or JS/Jquery and obtain specific data?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have a new design requirement that uses the facebook fan box unorthodoxically. Instead of 'hacking' the fan box, I'd rather scrape the fan box iframe (hidden) and retrieve the contents of the grid-item class in the .fan_box class (i.e. .fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item). I basically need the URLs to the face images and their links.

I'd prefer .NET methodology or JS/Jquery and something to get me started and pointed in the right direction. Please don't just provide a basic method to pull in a webpage to scrape, that's not the point. It's the iframe and accessing the data within it, is the challenge here.

I've not seen anyone try this and have searched thoroughly. I am not a expert so please give me more direction than you would give a brain-dead monkey. Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty or articles out there on accessing iframes with javascript. Please attempt something before asking for assistance. It is not appropriate to ask others to give detailed instructions on a problem you have not attempted.

Comment: Unfortunately, you failed to read the question entirely. See the Answer.

Comment: I did not fail to read the question. An API call is not scraping and iFrame. Its also a conclusion you could have easily reached with a google search. Futhermore, Igy did NOT give "more direction than you would give a brain-dead monkey". Having someone else do that menial research is still inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just access the page's /feed connection via the API and display it in your own style?

Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ (bear in mind you'll need an access token to access the feed)

A sample of the return type is here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552%2Ffeed